# Heroku error on deployment of app: 'Error: cannot find module '/app/index.js'

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy react-express apps to Heroku, so I've created a very simple app to do this. Its' a `create-react-app` front end with a express backend, with a dev server at localhost:3000 that proxies api calls to the server at localhost:5000.
However, I keep getting an 'Application error' whenever I try to load my app's URL, and after checking the error logs, I noticed the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Here's my project structure:

```
client
 +-build
 +-node_modules
public
 +-index.html
src
 +-App.js
 +-index.js
package.json
yarn.lock

server
 +-models
    +-reviews.js
 +-node_modules
 +-package.json
 +-server.js
 +-yarn.lock
```

And here's how I've configured my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Review = require('./models/reviews')
const path = require('path')

//Server
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

//Middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(cors())

//Mongo config
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://joshydsimon:Josh1985!@mochawelly.8cxdz.mongodb.net/MochaWelly?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
.then(() => {
    console.log('connected to db')
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

app.get('/api/all-reviews', (req,res) => {
  Review.find()
  .then((result) => {
      res.send(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  })
})

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Lastly, here's some scripts I added to the package.json (server side):

```
   "start": "node index.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
```

Comment: hey, I'm interested in if you find a solution since most tutorials online are for directories where the server and heroku postbuild script are in the main root.

Answer (score 1):

Its possibly not directing into your client folder?

```js
//Try this?

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Also try this:

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"}
```

Also try this:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(cors())
```